# How to automate the uni test code generation in MStest

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, nunit, mstest

I am using MSTest to unit test my code. if i want to automate the unit test code for all my public API, how do i do it.

I am using VS 2010 . I am new to MSTest . Can anyone guide me on how to acheive this?

Comment: If my answer has helped would you mind marking it as accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Pex, its a research project from Microsoft.

> Pex automatically generates test suites with high code coverage. Right from the Visual Studio code editor, Pex finds interesting input-output values of your methods, which you can save as a small test suite with high code coverage. Microsoft Pex is a Visual Studio add-in for testing .NET Framework applications.

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/